# Link and Offset in Glm

Tags: r, statistics, offset, glm

I need to create a GLM with dependent variable : `Q= A/r` where `A` has an overdispersed Poisson distribution and `r` is the exposure. `X` is the input variable. The model form is a Perks .

The link function is : log((3-Q)/Q).

Is the following line correct?

```
Mod1 <- glm( (3-A/offset(r))/(A/offset(r) ~ X,  
 data=dataname , family= quasipoisson(link=log), weights=r)
```

In particular:

1. Can I manipulate the dependent variable like that so i can only write "link=log"?
2. Did I put the offset in a proper way?